# Adding image in left side of a list (list has background ) when hover on the list?

Tags: html, css

I need a list with two background , one is visible and another one is hidden , When list is over on then 2nd image should be displayed with 1st image in left side of 1st image .

You can see this in facebook .In facebook group list , when we hover on any one of group  then it shows an addition icon for setting , I want to achieve this feature . Any help will be help full .

I have tried below code but not getting  , can some one fix this error .

```
<ul class="fav">
    <li> 
        <a href="#" class="page">
            <img src="image/page.png" alt="Page">Favourite Page
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="setting">
            <img source="image/setting2.png">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.fav {
    z-index:1;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    font-family: font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif Georgia, "Times New Roman";
    list-style: none;
}
.fav li {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:20px;
}
.fav li a {
    color: #42413C;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fav li a:visited {
    color: #6E6C64;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fav li a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fav li img {
    margin:0 10px 0px 0px;
}
.setting:hover {
    display:inline-block;
}
.setting {
    float: right;
    margin-left: -50px;
    color: tray;
    display: none;
}
.setting li:hover img {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to consider `jQuery` you can use this to hide/show your desired "settings" link:

```
$( "li" ).hover(function() {
$(this).find(".setting").toggleClass("settingVis");
});
```

and this CSS:

```
.setting{
    display: none;
}
.settingVis{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[SAMPLE in jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8nLBJ/8/)** -or- **[Using Just CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/8nLBJ/10/)**

Comment: @Froint setting is not showing in right side can you put setting  in left side as in facebook .

Comment: Can you put two image as , one is displayed for all time and another one is displayed when link is hovered . Like facebook group setting .

Comment: yeah like this , Thanks . Can i do this without using JQuery ?

Comment: It's not working for me due to class , since i have 3 list in a single file .Each list have different class name.

Comment: When we r using class to reference UL then it's not working , any  help will be appreciable .

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use divs instead of ul because you can use a css-trick:

```
.page:hover > .setting img {code here}
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/9zPk7/2/ is this what you want to achieve?

So you can display a small settings icon in the right bottom

Comment: Can you put two image as , one is displayed for all time and another one is displayed when link is hovered . Like facebook group setting .